# How to emitt a message to a listener every time when an array is updated?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have the following scenario:

- a service class that insert every 2 seconds into a static array a position (latitude, longitude).
- a map fragment and in **onReady()** method the **array getter method** is called and then the points are painted on the map, **the issue is when the background service insert more points into the array the getter method isn't called.**

So the question is **how to notify the onReady()** method to call the **getPoints()** method every time when **the array is updated**? (keep in mind that there are two separate threads).

**I need to implement some kind of listener in the onReady() method that listen for changes into the location array.**

I was thinking about something as in Node - event emitter -> event listener but I didn't find a way for this. Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

note the size of array before service execution it could be zero or depends on your logic.
now every time when array size get increased call the function that you want to perform by your logic.
Or if you seems this logic is difficult to implements  you can play with service, A services give response whenever it do some work you can call your function on that line.